# How does one politely stop other people from using one's mouse?

Tags: work-environment

What should one do if their workmate cleans their nose and ears with their hands and everyone in the team (10 people), from time to time, keep touching each other's mouse if someone needs assistance on their workstation?

I am not a super hygienic person myself, but this really seems like a health and safety issue to me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31051/discussion-on-question-by-ignacio-how-does-one-politely-stop-other-people-from-u).

Comment: Do you also intend to keep them from touching the door handle when they enter your office?

Comment: @rumtscho, most door handles can easily be opened with elbow, thus isolating yourself with your shirt's sleeve. WC doors can be opened using a paper towel from the dispenser.

Comment: @Vorac true and I use just one of my finger to open it, sometimes my leg

Comment: Seems like it is time for HR to say something about personal hygiene. (Let them look like the bad guys.) You might want to read what Gerald M. Weinberg said about hygiene problems in "*Becoming a Technical Leader*", which is geared toward programming work environments.

Comment: Can this question be extended to include: How to stop other employees from touching your computer screen.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have been through that recently. Here is one solution, an alternative to the accepted answer, which is also excellent.

Sit in your chair, in front of your monitor, mouse and keyboard. When the person, that you are collaborating with, reaches to touch your mouse, do not move your hand away from it. They will then ask you

--Could I have your mouse to show you something?
--Just tell me how to do it myself - you should reply.
--But it will be so much quicker if I do it!
--I need to learn and develop, please teach me - your response, or any other silly excuse.

I found this causing a little bit less confrontation than wiping the mouse in front of the offender and less anxiety than secretly doing so.

Comment: How utterly annoying! Learning how to do something yourself strongly includes doing it yourself, but suggesting to describe, for the first time, where exactly to click, especially in sequences, seems very exhausting.

Did you never try to describe to position of the windows start menu to a relative over the phone? ;)

It might also lead to people pointing at your screen, which many also consider bad for various reasons[citation needed].

Comment: @KjeldSchmidt, indeed it is annoying for the person helping you and could possibly lead to problems in the workplace. All I am saying is that IMHO this is a little less annoying than demonstratively wiping the device in front of them. **Another partial solution is to learn to do everything keyboard-only.** People will see this is your way and will tend to not impose their mouse-way on you.

Comment: It's not that hard, (*or even annoying, once you get used to it*), to explain where to click. And it's usually not hard to follow directions. Especially if both people are familiar with the basic buttons. If the person directing doesn't really know where they are supposed to click, that's when things get annoying. Communication skills help.

Comment: It might work, I guess. Though, I also assumed that you would wipe the mouse _after_ the people using the mouse leave. An explanation among the lines of "I have a weak immune system and don't want to miss work for chronic sniffles" should probably also work when confronted about this behaviour.

Comment: @KjeldSchmidt an explanation in the lines of "this is my mouse" could also work.

Answer (score 119):

Pretty simple solution:

[image]

I am not trying to be flippant, but you really can't force people to not touch their faces nor forbid them from touching your mouse.

Strictly speaking, you are correct, it is not proper etiquette.

The problem is that calling that out will backfire on you in most workplaces. Just wipe your hands and your stuff clean as needed.

Comment: +1 as this method is even [recommended by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-kw/HT201294). If this particular brand is not available, make sure whatever you buy doesn't contain bleach.

Comment: Conspicuously cleaning the thing after they've touched it also acts as a mild reproach if they've touched it without asking.

Comment: Using chemicals like this can cause severe problems for people who are allergic or sensitive to them. While that may not be the OP, someone close by might be that way.

Comment: @GreenMatt, there are milder alcohol-based wipes as well (I literally just picked the first image I found for wipes). Personally I feel the OP is overreacting to a minor hygiene issue, but if it bothers him, the best thing to do is to discreetly wipe down surfaces that cause him concern.

Comment: @teego1967: I agree with you on most points, I was just pointing out that such products carry their own risks, especially when something like "lemon scent" is added.

Comment: @GreenMatt, yes, of course, IMHO even antibacterial wipes can be cause for concern-- because it is sort of like taking bacteria to gym.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It really doesn't matter what Apple recommends, they are just disinfecting wipes (also known as Baby Wipes). Nothing special, and no reason to lend Apple any credence here.

Comment: The reason I mentioned Apple is because they have specific guidance - that if _this specific brand_ is not available, use any but ensure they don't have bleach.

Comment: @GreenMatt - +1 for suggesting that we could poison the offending person with chemicals.

Comment: @teego1967 I have a follow-up question to your answer. Is it better to clean the mouse discreetly out of the other person's sight? Or start cleaning it when they are done and start moving away? Cleaning it discreetly is more diplomatic obviously, otherwise I would be very offended because I offered to help this person and he treats me like a mangy dog. But on the other hand, the coworkers will quickly get the point to not to touch your mouse.

Comment: If the use of strong chemicals is a concern, teatree oil-based disinfectants are significantly less toxic and provide much of the same benefit.

Comment: If you use a wipe, I suggest wiping the mouse before passing it to the other person as well (or offering to wipe it if they've just grabbed it).  As Fixed Point commented, I would be offended if I see you wiping it after I've touched it - doing it both ways makes it more of a "general hygiene" point and less of a potential insult.

Answer (score 70):

At work I am using [a keyboard that does not have letters on it](http://www.daskeyboard.com/daskeyboard-4-ultimate/) - it's just black. A lot of my co-workers routinely get angry at me when they want to enter a password, so I provide them with a regular office keyboard that they can use to enter passwords or write text.

The same works for a mouse too. Just provide a *guest-mouse*. This is especially easy if your desk is large and visitors are usually sitting/kneeling on the same side. Just have a second office-issue mouse and leave it on that side.

If asked why, tell them it's easier because no-one needs to move chairs around, no cable pulling on the desk, and anyway your mouse cable is fixed to the table (because of office safety regulations).

As pointed out in the comments, it makes sense to store that mouse in a way that doesn't interrupt your work when someone bumps into your table. Put it upside down, use a cordless mouse that's switched off/in the charger or similar if that is an issue.

Comment: Try to get a heavy mouse as the second mouse though. This might seem like silly advice, but every time the second mouse gets focus it will interrupt whatever you're doing for an instant. Meaning if you get a cheap, light, small mouse that easily moves you might often loose focus.

Comment: Also if someone walks into your table this is fun. But of course you can store the mouse upside down until used.

Comment: Or a wireless one with a switch. Less messy, and you can turn it off when not in use.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek But then the OP will have to clean his mouse everytime someone used it, as to not touch the dirty mouse just to turn it off!

Comment: If OP never touches the guest mouse then there is not a problem I think.

Comment: If the question is about keeping them away from keyboard, why not using Dvorak keyboard?

Comment: @Ooker the question is about the mouse, not the keyboard. The blank keyboard part was just as an anecdote. Certainly using Dvorak is even more mean than having no letters. But the point is not to annoy the coworkers, just to make sure they don't touch your stuff without offending them.

Comment: I don't know the reason about your case, but for me, using the Dvorak is purely for efficiency. Surely it will irritate others, but I have a good excuse. Anyway, my point is only valid for keyboard, not mouse.

Comment: For people who need letters printed to type passwords, a dvorak keyboard (with printed letters) is still better than a blank Querty keyboard, I would guess.

Comment: I also have a *Das Keyboard* with no markings, and a trackball.  It has freaked out "support" people.  Just the other day someone refused to 'take the helm' to correct some Chinese text, and had to give detailed directions to me instead.  A guest mouse can be kept turned over, not plugged in (easy these days with USB) or "on blocks" to keep it from moving.

Answer (score 27):

An even simpler solution.

[image]

[[credit]](http://www.instantshift.com/2014/03/05/creative-computer-mouses/)

On a more serious note, if you're willing to start using your left hand for your mouse and left-handed trackball [mouse](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-trackball-m570?crid=7), I can pretty much guarantee that your right-handed co-workers will learn to stop touching it.

Imagine the image below, but for a left-hand, not a right-hand.
[image]

Comment: Ah crap I didn't see this answer! +1

Comment: If I need to use the mouse and it's a left handed one, I will probably touch it even more because every task I do with it will take longer. Also note that in some cultures the right hand is the "clean" hand (used for eating) and the left hand is considered dirty (used in the bathroom). So using a left-handed mouse might backfire.

Comment: Missing explanation for the first case. I dont get in howfar it would help by not using it? especially as the workspace of OP and his behaving sounds more like, him self would more likely avoid this mouse as his cowrokers would.

Comment: In fact,  I **do** use a LH trackball. Almost nobody can handle a trackball, so I keep a standard mouse connected as well for "visitors" to use.  If they infect each other, well... :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft me too. I have this exact mouse and I have a back "normal" mouse for when other people need to use it. For some reason nobody but me seems to like this mouse.

Comment: @Kilisi I have to say, you get used to a trackball pretty quickly - it's just different coordination.

Comment: +1 Count me in as a trackball fanboy. It's bloody perfect. I can even play fps games with it. And no one wants to use it :)

Comment: I'm not seeing how that's a LH trackball.  I see myself controlling the ball with my thumb on my right hand...

Comment: @Nelson, That's only because my left pinky is ginormous. It's five times bigger than my thumb. I would post a picture, but I'm afraid that would gross everybody out.

Comment: An alternative http://cdn.trendhunterstatic.com/thumbs/explosive-computing-grenade-mouse.jpeg

Answer (score 7):

The truth is that, no matter what you do, you will always be touching surfaces that can be potentially contaminated. Avoiding to share the mouse will not make the situation much better.

In my opinion, you should see the problem in the opposite way.

Assume that your hands will be dirty most of the time. The good news is that, in general, your skin will do its job preventing the germs from entering your body. What you should keep in mind that you should avoid touching in your mouth, eyes or any other mucosa with your hands unless you just washed your them first.

Answer (score 5):

I use a wireless trackball, and have a mouse plugged in.  I use the trackball, and everyone else prefers the mouse.

Alternately, use a wireless mouse yourself, and have a wired mouse connected nearby.  When someone wants to use your computer or you step away, hold onto your mouse, and they'll use the guest mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Get another mouse and put into a free USB port. Both Windows and Linux support multiple mouses no problem (any can move the mouse pointer).

This is often used in pair programming, and you will also save some time normally required to pass the mouse to the partner.

Hold the hand on your mouse and the partner will take and use another one, because it is free. If you need to come to another workstation, you can bring your own mouse too (may take 10 - 30 seconds till Windows understands the situation but later works fine).

Answer (score 1):

Use a wireless mouse+keyboard set with a usb dongle and always carry them with you to other workstations. When you don't want others to touch yours, simply put it inside a locking drawer and take the key with you.

When you need to control another person's computer, consider using a remote control software so you don't have to leave your workstation and touch other people's input devices.

A guest mouse and keyboard can be left on the table for when you're not available, and your wireless set is locked away.

Comment: Do you walk everywhere with your keyboard and mouse? Have you ever needed to take it to places where you normally don't? Like if you pass a colleague and you want to join him for a coffee, do you stay in the break room with a keyboard in hand? This seems like very odd behaviour. Much more so than whiping off your mouse.

Comment: If it is very important to not use anyone else's input devices, I suppose you could explain it to whomever you're having lunch with, and go grab your own from your desk after lunch.

Comment: @Reaces, This wearable mouse should do the trick. http://images.gizmag.com/hero/airmouse.jpg Hot coffee? No problem. The mouse insulates you. Running low on toilet paper. The mouse knows and directly orders a roll from Amazon (patent pending).

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on the vibe at your workstation, if you want to make a humorous approach at solving this dispute, why not print out a paper in all caps saying something cheesy, like "Get Your Hands Off My Mouse" and then have a picture of a mouse (The rodent) behind it. It will hopefully make them laugh, and get the idea.

Or, you could just take out the mouse when you leave. And if it's stuck into your computer, just buy your own mouse and bring that wherever you go.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: I don't find this amusing at all and would be rather offended at all-caps commands given via some print out paper. It seems rather impolite to me.

Comment: This definitely doesn't meat the criteria of "polite" and I can't imagine a scenario where this is any kind of net positive.

Comment: Seems like fodder for passiveaggressivenotes.com

Comment: I like it. It's light-hearted, humourous and meaningful. What's "impolite" is using somebody else's machine. I _hate_ that.

Comment: The idea that people might genuinely find this suggestion offensive is very silly.

Comment: At the same office that I mention in my answer, there was a guy with an A4 sheet on the back of his monitor, saying "If I have my earphones on, FUCK OFF". No one ever found that offensive. IMO this entirely depends on the office culture.

Answer (score 0):

There are several people in my office who can't help themselves to reach forward to take control of the mouse, type on the keyboard, or touch the computer screen. I have found that moving my chair between the person and the mouse/keyboard/screen to block their access can work very well.